# layer.border doesn't work?

Tags: swift, uiview

```
let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 200, height: 180))
let view1sub = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 90, height: 90))

view1.addSubview(view1sub)
view1sub.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

 view1sub.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

[image]

```
view1.layer.borderWidth =  3.0
view1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
view1sub.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
view1sub.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

[image]

I use the code above to add a border to `view1`.

I want to add a border to the `view1sub` by using the same code.

To my surprise, the background color of `view1sub` is changed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layer.border is working for **view1sub**. you're just not able to see because your **view1sub** background color is red. Change background to other color you can see then.